# Concatenation of exploded array of tags to a string with links

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, explode, string-concatenation

With my custom function below, my aim is to give a specific link to each element of array of tags. My input to the function is a **string** like (tag1, tag2, tag3). My output is (in linked form) `tag1,`

“tag1,” is okey but why can not I get what I expect : “tag1, tag2, tag3” (in linked form)

I read examples in php.net and in this site for the terms (`array`, `explode`, `for`, `.=`) but I couldn’t solve my issue.

Can you guide me please

```
function tag_linkify ($article_tags)
{
$array_of_tags = explode(",", $article_tags);
$sayac = count($array_of_tags);
$linked_tags ="";
for ($i=0; $i<$sayac; $i++)
    {
        $linked_tags .= '<a href="'.'">'.$array_of_tags[$i].'</a>, ';
    }
echo substr_replace($linked_tags, '', -1, 2);
}

tag_linkify (tag1,tag2,tag3);
```

Thanks
Regards

Comment: You'd better qualify, is input a string: tag_linkify ("tag1,tag2,tag3"); or is input 3 args? tag_linkify ($tag1,$tag2,$tag3);

Comment: @Cups thank you. Only tag_linkify ("tag1,tag2,tag3"); change solved my issue. So my issue was I didn't qualified my input as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving on Sedz post:

```
function tag_linkify ($article_tags)
{
$array_of_tags = explode(",", $article_tags);
echo '<a href="">' . implode('</a>,<a href="">', $array_of_tags) . '</a>';
}
```

tag_linkify ("tag1,tag2,tag3");

Btw. the parameters in your tag_linkify call  miss their quotation marks and

```
'<a href="'.'">'
```

is really the same as

```
'<a href="">'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out with use of **`implode`**

```
function tag_linkify ()
{
$array_of_tags = get_func_args();;
$sayac = count($array_of_tags);
$linked_tags =array();
for ($i=0; $i<$sayac; $i++)
    {
        $linked_tags[] = '<a href="'.'">'.$array_of_tags[$i].'</a> ';
    }
echo "(".implode(',', $lined_tags).")";
}

tag_linkify (tag1,tag2,tag3);
```

I hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly i would do:

```
tag_linkify ($tag1, $tag2, $tag3);

function tag_linkify () 
{

    $tags = get_func_args(); // get all tags in an array
    $final = '';
    // loop through the tags
    forech($tags as $tag)
    {
        // return or echo depends on what you doing with your data
        $final .='<a href="">'. $tag . '</a>'; 
    }

    return $final;
}
```

[get_func_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)